# Monotouch access private API with return type

Tags: c#, ios, video, xamarin.ios, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to port the following code to mirror My App's display to an external display via the VGA adapter.

https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager/blob/master/TVOutManager.m

This code optionally accesses `UIGetScreenImage();` which returns a `CGImageRef` object. How can i call this Private API from Monotouch? I want to use this method only for an internal build of my app for trade shows.

I have seen several solutions, but none talks about how to call a selector with a return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGImageRef's MonoTouch wrapper, `CGImage`, has a static property `ScreenImage`. You can get a screenshot with this property, I haven't used it though.

Details on binding Objective-C objects (including returning selector values) can be found here: http://monotouch.net/index.php?title=Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types/Binding_Details&highlight=bind

Comment: A note to anyone who reads this: CGImage.ScreenImage will not work on the simulator, but it does work on the device.